# How to detect (say) 2 seconds of inactivity in swift?

Tags: swift, nstimer

This question could be rephrased as: How to invoke a function if 2 seconds pass without an event (re)occurring?

I'm playing with `SFSpeechRecogniser`. While the user is speaking it sends continuous updates (maybe 2-3 per second). I'm trying to detect when the user stops speaking. If I don't receive any updates for (say) 2 seconds, I can assume that the user has paused speaking.

How to implement this in Swift?

I am aware that I could do:

```
var timer : Timer?

func f() {
    on_event = { result, error in
        print( "Got event, restarting timer" )
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false) { _ in
            print( "2s inactivity detected" )
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            NotificationCenter.default.post( name: inactivity_notification,  object: nil )
        }
    }
}
```

But is it possible to do it without repeatedly creating and destroying the Timer instance (and thus creating a boatload of temporary Timer instances that never get used)?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use a timer here? How about GCD or OperationQueue?

Comment: @algrid Thanks, I'll reformulate the question to a WHAT (rather than a HOW).

Comment: The thing is that your example is actually a good way of doing it :) And they are not "never get used", they are used, every time you create a new one. That's a simple and proper way to track timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to:

1. Record the current time when an event occurs
2. Set up a recurring timer with a granularity you are comfortable with (for example `0.25` seconds).
3. When the timer pops, check difference between current time and last event time.  If that is greater than `2` seconds, fire your notification.

This is what I'd do if I had to recognize that a person had stopped typing for `2` seconds.  Invalidating and creating timers at typing speed would be a lot of churn.  You can tune this to your requirements depending on how close to exactly `2` seconds you need to be.

You could also do this by just having a `timeSinceLastEvent` variable, and set it to `0` when an event occurs.  The recurring timer would increment this by the granularity, and check if it has reached `2` seconds and fire the notification if it had.  This is cruder than doing the time math since the timer interval isn't guaranteed, but simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Timer's .fireDate property is writable.

So every time a speech event occurs just do `timer.fireDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2)`

Comment: I like the look of this approach, but I can't see how to implement a complete solution.